# Why do I only get 53 tracks from a Spotify playlist instead of 100 tracks? (using selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, spotify

I'm a python beginner trying to use Selenium to retrieve all the songs in a Spotify playlist. All of sudden my code stops working after the 53rd song, although there are 100 songs. I have tried x-paths and css selectors. I can't see a change in the class of the song or anything like that. My code:

```
URL = "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/3kx1rGFZk6QOhgKYqyRNUJ"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
driver.get(url=URL)
time.sleep(5)
data = driver.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".iCQtmPqY0QvkumAOuCjr div")

for song in data:
    print(song.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Could it be that the find_elements method has a limit?

I appreciate your responses,
john

Comment: probably because they are out of reach and not loaded yet, try scroll to the bottom of the page

Comment: Spotify has an api where you can just request the values.